# Snake game in Python using Turtle graphics error

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

So I've been trying to follow up this guide on how to create a Snake game using Turtle graphics with Python: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rrOqlfMujqQ&ab_channel=ChristianThompson
Basically, I cannot get the "snake" to actually move. I am getting a gray screen, with the snake, and it is stuck. (Supposed to move when clicking "w/s/d/a").

**The error I am receiving:**
`raise Terminator
turtle.Terminator`

**And the program I wrote is:**

```
import turtle
import time

delay = 0.1

# Set up Screen
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Snake Game By Aviv Sabati")
wn.bgcolor("gray")
wn.setup(width=600, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

# Snake Head
head = turtle.Turtle()
head.speed(0)
head.shape("square")
head.color("green")
head.penup()
head.goto(0,0)
head.direction = "stop"

# functions
def go_up():
    head.directin = "up"

def go_down():
    head.directin = "down"

def go_right():
    head.directin = "left"

def go_left():
    head.directin = "right"

def move():
    if head.direction == "up":
        y = head.ycor()
        head.sety(y + 20)

    if head.direction == "down":
        y = head.ycor()
        head.sety(y - 20)

    if head.direction == "left":
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x - 20)

    if head.direction == "right":
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x + 20)

#Keybord binding

wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(go_up, "w")
wn.onkeypress(go_down, "s")
wn.onkeypress(go_left, "a")
wn.onkeypress(go_right, "d")

#Main Game Loop

while True:
    wn.update()

    move()

    time.sleep(delay)

wn.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You misspelt "direction" as "directin" in the following functions "go_up", "go_down", "go_right", and "go_left". I also noticed that your "go_left" sets the direction to right, and "go_right" sets it to left.

The "go direction" section of your code should look like this:

```py
def go_up():
    head.direction = "up"

def go_down():
    head.direction = "down"

def go_right():
    head.direction = "right"

def go_left():
    head.direction = "left"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Can you please explain to me how you solve it? It will help me and other newbies in the future!